# Chat Conversion Not Displayed in View - QuickBlox iOS Setup

Tags: quickblox

Chat conversion not become visible after I changed my QuickBlox account. Before developer has setup chatting for my iOS application with his personal QuickBlox account so I require to switch it with my company QuickBlox account and later on I can do purchase of plans without any barrier.

After this change actual send messages didn't become visible on both side devices before this was working properly after my account change it get stopped in working. I was getting few errors on log related to this so please check:

[image]

Though multiple users get created in account so definitely connection with QuickBlox has been establish as per my thinking but message passing not working.

In chatting view, I have sent many messages but nothing appear on screen, remain as it is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 2 days with this problem, I found solution for this problem. Posting here as an answer so that other users will not consume more time for this problem.

At QuickBlox dashboard, you have to enable retrieve users list permission so that other user can get list of others information. By default this flag set to disable so you have to enable it. Here is screenshot for the same:

[image]